# Laravel - Is it possible to pass object|array parameter for authenticating broadcasts in privatechannel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, broadcast

UserController.php

```
event(new MyEvent($MyObject));
```

MyEvent.php

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('check-validity.'.$this->MyObject);
}
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('check-validity.{MyObject}', function ($user, $MyObject) {
    $sameMyObject = MyModel::where('some_id', $MyObject->some_id)
        ->where('state', 1000)
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->where('some_other_id', $MyObject->some_other_id)
        ->first();

    if($sameMyObject)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

I have a table named `MyTable` as an example which has some columns.
The more important ones are: `some_id`, `user_id`, `some_other_id`. When a user triggers `event(new MyEvent($MyObject))`, the content of `$MyObject` is an object of himself BUT what I want to check here in `Broadcast::channel('check-validity...` is whether the other user has the same row in `MyTable` with some differences which could be `->where('state', 1000)` or not. If there was, so to send only to that user(the concept of authenticating for that user).

Now my question is that is it possible to pass object|array to `Broadcast::channel`? if yes how can I pass the other user's data about this `$MyObject` in Echo? I'm asking this because before this I could pass other user data which was ONLY ONLY `user_id` that I made an html tag and got the value to pass it through the channel: `window.Echo.private('valid-user.' + user_id)` but now instead of that `user_id` I don't know how can I pass a `MyObject` content to be authenticated due to those sql multiple conditions should be set.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try serializing your array like so

```
$a= array("john" => 120,"dave" => 342,"joe" => 553);
print_r($a);
echo "<br/>";
$b=serialize($a);
echo $b."<br/>";
$c=unserialize($b);
print_r($c);
```

But to send a `model` do this

```
use App\Order;

Broadcast::channel('order.{order}', function ($user, Order $order) {
    return $user->id === $order->user_id;
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks